# How can I change the current font on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

It's really urgent. I searched it but couldn't find.

After the installing "Helvetica" fonts on my computer, some of the websites' fonts' started to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Z0c.jpg

How can I change this permanently without the deleting fonts?

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, click on Settings, then the 'Advanced' link at the bottom of the page. Once that menu expands, go to 'Web Content' section and click on 'Customize Fonts'. There you can choose your default font and click on 'Ok' to save changes.

Comment: I already did it but it doesn't work too... If the site have "Helvetica" in their css code, it renders as Helvetica not the other one.